# How to solve Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to insert dynamically checkbox value in MySQL database, now the problem is Array to string conversion

I am tried to insert dynamically checkbox value

This is Controller.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'com_name'  =>'required',
            'per_name'  =>'required',
            'price'     =>'required',
            'email'     =>'required',
            'mobile'    =>'required',
            'status'    =>'required',
            'service'   =>'required',
            'source'    =>'required',
            'address'   =>'required',
            'update'    =>'required'
        ]);

        //Create Dalywork
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $user                    = Auth::User()->id;
            $dailyworks              = new Dailywork;
            $dailyworks->com_name    = $request->input('com_name');
            $dailyworks->user_id     = $user;
            $dailyworks->per_name    = $request->input('per_name');
            $dailyworks->price       = $request->input('price');
            $dailyworks->email       = $request->input('email');
            $dailyworks->mobile      = $request->input('mobile');
            $dailyworks->status      = $request->input('status');
            $dailyworks->service     = $request->input('service');
            $dailyworks->source      = $request->input('source');
            $dailyworks->address     = $request->input('address');
            $dailyworks->update      = $request->input('update');
            $dailyworks->save();

            return redirect()->route('dailywork.index')->with('success','Report hsa been Create Successfully');

            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($dailyworks);    
        }

    }
```

My HTML Code

```
@foreach($service as $services)
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{$services->service}}" > {{$services->service}}
   </label>
@endforeach
```

I expect the output save but the is an error Array to string conversion

Comment: by converting the array to a string? It would seem, `$services->service` is an array, not a string.

Comment: you could use `implode()` or `json_encode()` or make `service` an array. It depends on what you need

Comment: **Give `name` attribute to input** . This is `$request->input('service')` array implode it or convert this into a string